# Forward app through SSH

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, port-forwarding

I would like to forward app from one server to another through SSH.

Let me explain.

I have two servers, one with root privileges, full firewall/iptables/ports/apps/etc. control but it's private.

On second I only have SSH account and few ports to use but it's public.

I installed XMPP server on first server and use 5222 and 5269 ports (I can change them, its not a problem). How can I forward 2 ports from public server to private?

Private server should be only like proxy for network activity:

User <---- port 5300 ----> public server <---- any port ----> private server

I tried to use dynamic forwarding, but without results.
Local forwarding, it's ok, but only from private machine (tested on web server and curl/wget), not working outside.

Answer (score 2):

You could try to multihop SSH connections. Your public server will need pseudo-tty allocation in order to make the second connection, as well as X forwarding enabled.
The command would be something like this:

```
ssh -t -X $public ssh -X $private
```

Then execute your X commands (like XMPP chat client) as you normally would.
As X forwarding requires quite a bit of bandwidth, you'll want to experiment with the -C option as well for server-side compression.

Multihop answer was found [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41493/how-to-ssh-to-a-server-using-another-server).